# Did Rama follow brahmacharya during aranyavasa?

Tags: scripture, rama, brahmacharya

I recently heard that Rama followed brahmacharya during his aranya-vasa, which is very likely to be true.

Which scripture says it?

Comment: He wasn't a celibate during vanvasa neither was he a sanyasi (a kshatriya cant be sanyasi). However, if the word brahmacharya means the larger definition of being a satvik and pious person than that is a different story.

Comment: I had read somewhere that brahmacharya is followed after marriage as well if a person follows certain conditions even though he / she can engage in kaam.

Comment: Bharat does claim that Ram maintained Brahmacharya until he left for vanvaas. He was married for many years before that. - Ayodhya Kand, Sarga 82, Sholka 11. https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=2&language=dv&field_sarga_value=82 . This is confirmed by Sita as well, as stated in https://qr.ae/pGoeoq